# Iterate attributes of property, typecast and store info if found

Tags: c#

Im constructing metadata about a class. With reflection i iterate over the class properties, and those properties have attributes (name, validation etc). When iterating those attributes, i typecast to some specific attribute-types, and if successful store the relevant attribute information. Im looking to do this in a more elegant way since there is much code repetition at this point. In part the typecast checks (`attibute as Attributetype`), and also the check if Validate is null, and then new-ing it up is repetitive (Validate needs to be null if there are no validation attributes). I expect the number of attribute-types to grow

Ideal would be to define what attribute-types im looking for, and if found execute relevant code.

```
foreach (Attribute attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true))
{

    //Info attribute
    DisplayAttribute display = attribute as DisplayAttribute; 
    if (display != null)
    {
        Name =display.Name;
        Group = display.GroupName;
        Description = display.Description;
    }

    //Validation attributes
    MinLengthAttribute min = attribute as MinLengthAttribute;
    if (min != null)
    {
        if (Validate == null) Validate = new MetaValidate();
        Validate.MinLength = min.Length;
    }

    MaxLengthAttribute max = attribute as MaxLengthAttribute;
    if (max != null)
    {
        if (Validate == null) Validate = new MetaValidate();
        Validate.MaxLength = max.Length;
    }

    RegularExpressionAttribute regex = attribute as RegularExpressionAttribute;
    if (regex != null)
    {
        if (Validate == null) Validate = new MetaValidate();
        Validate.Regex = regex.Pattern;
        Validate.RegexError = regex.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like ive found a great solution, my entire loop can be rewritten as this:

```
InvokeOnAttr<DisplayAttribute>(property, a => {
    Name = a.Name;
    Group = a.GroupName;
    Description = a.Description;
});

InvokeOnAttr<MinLengthAttribute>(property, a => {
    Validate.MinLength = a.Length;
});

InvokeOnAttr<MaxLengthAttribute>(property, a => {
    Validate.MaxLength = a.Length;
});

InvokeOnAttr<RegularExpressionAttribute>(property, a => {
    Validate.Regex = a.Pattern;
    Validate.RegexError = a.ErrorMessage;
});
```

If this method also is availible in the class (it takes a property, finds the attribute (of type TAttr provided), and if found executes the passed in action on it:

```
public void InvokeOnAttr<TAttr>(PropertyInfo p, Action<TAttr> action) where TAttr : Attribute {
    TAttr attr = p.GetCustomAttribute<TAttr>();
    if (attr is ValidationAttribute)
    {
        if (Validate == null) Validate = new MetaValidate();
    }
    if (attr != null) { 
        action.Invoke(attr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code.

If you want you can use linq if performance is not critical. PseudoCode:

```
var displayAttribute = type.GetProperties()
                           .SelectMany(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                           .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
                           .SingleOrDefault();
if (displayAttribute != null)
{
    ...      
}
```

Nice and declarative, you see what the code does at a glance. And you can compose with `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault` etc. as you need.

---

For the validation thing a factory method cleans things up:

```
private static MetaValidate CreateMetaValidate(
    MinLengthAttribute minAttribute, 
    MaxLengthAttribute maxAttribute,
    RegularExpressionAttribute regexAttribute)
{
    var validate = new MetaValidate
    {
        Min = minAttribute?.Min ?? 0,
        Max = maxAttribute?.Max ?? 16,
        ...
    };

    return validate;
}
```

Again pseudocode unless it happens to compile.

Thought of one thing that might be a pretty big smell:

What is up with the property initializers? When the data is read from attributes it feels like it should be readonly. If there is not a reason that they are mutable you should make the properties readonly and use constructor.